# mySQL Value Not In Data And In Data - huh?

Tags: mysql

Using MySQL.
Trying to understand a query with that looks for values not in results of other queries.  Seems like I should get back a value of 74, for a value that is not in the results of the other queries, but instead, I am getting back 0 rows returned.....

Table name = phpbb3x_forums.
One of the rows in the table has forum_id = 74.
Table viewable here: http://launchpad-001.com/_scoreboard/_symposium_merge/stackhelp/db_viewer/sql.php?db=stackhelp&table=phpbb3x_forums#PMAURL-0:sql.php?db=stackhelp&table=phpbb3x_forums  You can also run these queries at that link.

Forum_id 74  is not in the results of any of the following 3 queries:

```
select l0.forum_id
FROM step2_02_for.phpbb3x_forums l0
left join  phpbb3x_forums l1 on l0.forum_id = l1.parent_id
left join  phpbb3x_forums l2 on l1.forum_id = l2.parent_id
left join  phpbb3x_forums l3 on l2.forum_id = l3.parent_id
where l0.parent_id = 0

select l1.forum_id
FROM step2_02_for.phpbb3x_forums l0
left join  phpbb3x_forums l1 on l0.forum_id = l1.parent_id
left join  phpbb3x_forums l2 on l1.forum_id = l2.parent_id
left join  phpbb3x_forums l3 on l2.forum_id = l3.parent_id
where l0.parent_id = 0

select l2.forum_id
FROM step2_02_for.phpbb3x_forums l0
left join  phpbb3x_forums l1 on l0.forum_id = l1.parent_id
left join  phpbb3x_forums l2 on l1.forum_id = l2.parent_id
left join  phpbb3x_forums l3 on l2.forum_id = l3.parent_id

where l0.parent_id = 0
```

So, I expect to get back forum_id=74 when running the following

```
select forum_id from step2_02_for.phpbb3x_forums 
where forum_id not in 

(select l0.forum_id
FROM step2_02_for.phpbb3x_forums l0
left join  step2_02_for.phpbb3x_forums l1 on l0.forum_id = l1.parent_id
left join  step2_02_for.phpbb3x_forums l2 on l1.forum_id = l2.parent_id
left join  step2_02_for.phpbb3x_forums l3 on l2.forum_id = l3.parent_id
where l0.parent_id = 0 )

and forum_id not in 
(select l1.forum_id
FROM step2_02_for.phpbb3x_forums l0
left join  step2_02_for.phpbb3x_forums l1 on l0.forum_id = l1.parent_id
left join  step2_02_for.phpbb3x_forums l2 on l1.forum_id = l2.parent_id
left join  step2_02_for.phpbb3x_forums l3 on l2.forum_id = l3.parent_id
where l0.parent_id = 0)


and forum_id not in 
(select l2.forum_id
FROM step2_02_for.phpbb3x_forums l0
left join  step2_02_for.phpbb3x_forums l1 on l0.forum_id = l1.parent_id
left join  step2_02_for.phpbb3x_forums l2 on l1.forum_id = l2.parent_id
left join  step2_02_for.phpbb3x_forums l3 on l2.forum_id = l3.parent_id
where l0.parent_id = 0)
```

Instead, I am getting no rows returned.

When running the following, it works as expected:

```
select forum_id from step2_02_for.phpbb3x_forums 
where forum_id not in 

(select l0.forum_id
FROM step2_02_for.phpbb3x_forums l0
left join  step2_02_for.phpbb3x_forums l1 on l0.forum_id = l1.parent_id
left join  step2_02_for.phpbb3x_forums l2 on l1.forum_id = l2.parent_id
left join  step2_02_for.phpbb3x_forums l3 on l2.forum_id = l3.parent_id
where l0.parent_id = 0 )

and forum_id not in 
(select l1.forum_id
FROM step2_02_for.phpbb3x_forums l0
left join  step2_02_for.phpbb3x_forums l1 on l0.forum_id = l1.parent_id
left join  step2_02_for.phpbb3x_forums l2 on l1.forum_id = l2.parent_id
left join  step2_02_for.phpbb3x_forums l3 on l2.forum_id = l3.parent_id
where l0.parent_id = 0)
```

Values returned for that include 74 and all the others I expect.

Any help with this would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine the problem you are facing with `not in` is that the subqueries are returning `NULL` values.  The easiest fix is to just put in `where <col> is not null` to prevent this.

Consider the simple condition `where col in (A, B, C, NULL)`.  If `col` takes on `A`, `B`, or `C` then the query returns true.  Otherwise it returns unknown, which is treated as false.

Now, change the condition to `not in`:  `where col not in (A, B, C, NULL)`.  Two things can happen.  When `col` is `A`, `B`, or `C`, the `not in` returns false.  For any other values, it returns unknown, which is treated as false.  In other words, *if there is a `NULL` value in the list, then `NOT IN` never returns true*.

The "real" solution is to stop using `NOT IN` and to use `NOT EXISTS` instead.  Here is the transformation.  When you write:

```
 where y.col not in (select col2 from table x)
```

You really mean:

```
 where not exists (select 1 from table x where x.col2 = y.col)
```